# Sharing a vector across multiple functions and my program isn't working as intended.

Tags: c++, vector, console-application

I am currently trying to make a little console application that allows me to add strings to a string vector and I am having some issues. Whilst this code looks as though it should work, it seems that attempting to insert name into the names vector and list the names vector aren't working for some reason.

```
   #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

//Add a name to the vector
void AddName(std::vector<std::string> names)
{
    std::string name;

    std::cout << "Enter full name.";
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::getline(std::cin, name);

    names.push_back(name);
}

//List all names within vector
void ListNames(std::vector<std::string> names)
{
    std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter;

    for (iter = names.begin(); iter != names.end(); iter++)
    {
        std::cout << *iter << "\n";
    }
}

//Main function
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> names;

    int menuChoice = 0;

    do
    {
        std::cout << ("1: Add Name.");

        std::cin >> menuChoice;

        switch (menuChoice)
        {
        case 1:
            AddName(names);
            break;

        case 2:
            ListNames(names);
            break;

        }
    } while (menuChoice != 3);

    std::string barn;
    std::cin >> barn;

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are passing the vector by value instead of by reference.

Comment: I wouldn't repeat `std::vector<std::string>` so many places, I would make a `typedef`, perhaps named `StringContainer` and use that. DRY principle. If you have a noun more specific than "String", definitely use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is making a full copy of the vector.  That means that the version in each function is independent.

```
void ListNames(std::vector<std::string> names)
```

Creates a new vector based on the parameter which is a deep copy. (Internal objects may be shared.

```
void ListNames(std::vector<std::string> & names)
```

Sends the existing vector in, allowing it to be modified.

Answer (score 2):

You are copying the vector, creating a temporary instance within AddName and ListName. Your function declarations should be reference

```
void ListNames(std::vector<std::string>& names);
void AddName(std::vector<std::string>& names);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function gets a copy of the vector names, therefore anything which gets added to it is thrown away when the function returns. Use a reference instead:

```
void AddName(std::vector<std::string>& names)
```